# I need help solving this related rates equation.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need help answering the following question and I'll show you what I have.[image]
!

$$x=20,y=\sqrt{2100},z=50, \frac{dy}{dt}=30$$so differentiating $(20)^2+y^2=z^2$ $$2y\frac{dy}{dt}=2z\frac{dz}{dt}$$ And plugging in what I know(Probably wrong on some values)$$\frac{2\sqrt{2100}*30}{100}=27.495$$ Which according to the screenshot is wrong so I was wondering how to correctly approach the problem and what I did wrong. All help is appreciated.

EDIT: I now know I went about this problem the completely wrong way and that  I need to use trig functions. If anyone would mind explaining that, it'd be great though.

Comment: Calculus uses radians as a measure of angles.  You should to convert the 30 deg/s to rad/s.

Comment: So just substitute 30deg/s to $pi/6$?

Comment: That is part of it, if you label the vertical edge $y$, you get that $\tan \theta = y/20$ and you can differentiate that.

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate on jbtimmer's answer:

You are given a right triangle with a known leg of 20, that is constant. You also know that at a certain instant, the spot of light is 50 feet away from the cruiser, or is the length of the hypotenuse.

However, we don't need to use the length of the hypotenuse to solve this problem. Consider this: $$\tan(\theta) = \frac{y}{20}$$

If we differentiate, we get that $$\sec^2(\theta)*\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{1}{20}*\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Now, we now the value for $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, which is $\frac{\pi}{6}$, we can plug that in. However, we don't know the value for $\theta$ so we are going to find that now.

We know that y = $\sqrt{2100}$ from the Pythagorean theorem.

**This is where is gets a bit tricky. Try to follow my steps clearly.**

From your original post we got that $$(20)^2+y^2=z^2$$

And then from differentiating $$2y\frac{dy}{dt}=2z\frac{dz}{dt}$$

Using the right triangle again we can get that $$\sec(\theta) = \frac{z}{20}$$

Differentiating: $$\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)*\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{1}{20}*\frac{dz}{dt}$$

Simplifying this equation and the other trig equation we got earlier:

$$\sec^2(\theta)*\frac{10\pi}{3} = \frac{dy}{dt}$$

$$\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)*\frac{10\pi}{3} = \frac{dz}{dt}$$

Substituting these 2 equations into our new equation:

$$y\frac{dy}{dt}=z\frac{dz}{dt}$$

$$\sqrt{2100}*\sec^2(\theta)*\frac{10\pi}{3}=50*\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)*\frac{10\pi}{3}$$

Cleaning this up:

$$\sqrt{2100}*\sec(\theta)=50*\tan(\theta)$$

$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{2100}}{50}$$

We don't even have to solve for $\theta$, since we know $\sin(\theta)$, we can find $$\sec(\theta) = \frac{50}{\sqrt{2100}}$$

Now, Plugging it all in:

$$\frac{2500}{2100}*\frac{10\pi}{3} = \frac{dy}{dt}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{250\pi}{63}$$

Answer (score -1):

The light is moving at $30^\circ/s=\frac{30}{360} \cdot 2\pi \text{ radians }/s = \frac \pi 6 /s$.

Since the arc length of a circle is equal to $r\cdot \phi$ where $\phi$ is the angle subtended by the arc, the total speed that the light is travelling at a distance $l$ away is $\frac \pi 6 l /s$.

The angle between this direction of travel (the arc) and the wall where the light is shining is $\theta = \arctan \frac {50}{20}$, and so the speed of travel *along the wall* is the cosine of this angle times the total speed of the light along the arc at that distance $l$.

$$\theta = \arctan \frac 5 2$$
$$l=\sqrt{20^2 + 50^2} ft$$

The speed of the light at this point on the wall is:
$$\cos \theta \cdot l \cdot (\frac \pi 6 /s)$$
$$=\frac{10\pi}{3} ft/s$$
$$\approx 10.5 ft/s$$

Perhaps I've made a mistake, but the 'correct' answer given to you by the question seems to be wrong. $75.9 ft/s$ seems implausible because the car would have to be much further than $20 ft$ away.